# On Symfony2, is it a bad practice to use a Controller which return a non-Response value for another Controller?

Tags: php, symfony, controller, routes

I believe that the flow of Symfony2 is the following : Request -> Controller -> Response.

Actually, with this code, `MessageController` is not returning a response Object, but only a value for another Controller :

`MessageController` of `Compagny/MessageBundle` :

```
<?php
class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function getAction()
    {
        $message = "I display this message";
        return $message; // It's not a new Response object, it returns only a value
    }
}
```

`InterfaceController` of `Compagny/InterfaceBundle` :

```
<?php
class InterfaceController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $data = $this->forward('MessageBundle:Message:get');
        $response = new Response($data);
        return $response; // This one return a Response object
    }
}
```

Is this code a bad practice ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Because if you decide later to use Message::get directly, you won't be able to do it or fix it without changing InterfaceController.

I suggest this:

```
class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function getAction()
    {
        $message = "I display this message";
        return $this->createResponse($message);
    }
}
class InterfaceController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $forwardedResponse = $this->forward('MessageBundle:Message:get');
        $response = new Response($forwardedResponse->getContent());
        return $response; // This one return a Response object
    }
}
```